# Como deletar diretórios contendo sub diretórios e arquivos em um servidor FTP no Delphi?

Tags: delphi, ftp, diretório, delete, object-pascal

Estou à algum tempo tentando fazer com que minha aplicação feita no Delphi 2010 remova um diretório em um servidor FTP, utilizei o TIdFTP para tal tarefa com o comando "RemoveDir", mas o processo falha, pois segundo a aplicação o diretório não está vazio. O que posso fazer para solucionar meu problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Até onde sei, o Indy não possui um método "pronto" para o que deseja. Você terá que criar um método recursivo para apagar todos arquivos e subdiretórios antes de remover o diretório raiz. Veja este exemplo abaixo adaptado de um código obtido no site [progtown.com](http://www.progtown.com/topic1131698-removal-of-a-folder-with-files-idftp.html) :

```
procedure FTPRemoveDir(Dir: string);
var
  I: Integer;
  List: TStringList;
begin
  List := TStringList.Create;
  try
    FTP.ChangeDir(Dir);
    FTP.List(List, '', false);
    for i := 0 to List.Count - 1 do
    begin
      if FTP.Size(List[I]) = -1 then
        DelFTPDir(List[I])
      else
        FTP.Delete(List[I]);
    end;
    FTP.ChangeDirUp;
    FTP.RemoveDir(Dir);
  finally
    List.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Espero ter ajudado! Abraço!